# Send HTTP Command using VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to send an HTTP command using VB.NET and I'm not quite sure how to do it.  I don't want to actually navigate to the page, just execute the command.

```
http://xbmc.local/xbmcCmds/xbmcHttp?command=ExecBuiltIn&parameter=XBMC.updatelibrary%28video%29
```

What I'm doing is building an integrated interface for my XBMC home theater, and my home automation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WebRequest object to send an HTTP Request.

```
' Create a WebRequest object with the specified url. ' 
Dim myWebRequest As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)

' Send the WebRequest and wait for response. ' 
Dim myWebResponse As WebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

The [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) class has a number of properties you can check to see if the request succeeded or not.  And just something to be aware of, `GetResponse()` will throw an exception if it times out.

Comment: Is there a way to Response.Write the myWebResponse?

Comment: Of course ;)  Check out the example on the documentation page for the GetResponseStream() method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
Dim client = WebRequest.Create("http://xbmc.local/xbmcCmds/xbmcHttp?command=ExecBuiltIn&parameter=XBMC.updatelibrary%28video%29")
Dim response = client.GetResponse()
```